# Create div & and then div inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, class, append, appendchild

I can create a new div with the following syntax:

```
function createClass() {
 const firstDiv = document.createElement('div')
 firstDiv.classList.add('class1')
 container.appendChild(firstDiv)
}
```

Next I want to create a new div inside of that div. I tried the same syntax without success:

```
function createClass() {
 const firstDiv = document.createElement('div')
 firstDiv.classList.add('class1')
 container.appendChild(firstDiv)

 const secondDiv = document.createElement('div')
 secondDiv.classList.add('class2')
 firstDiv.appendChild(secondDiv)
}
```

If I use the following syntax it works, but there is a problem. If the function is executed more than once, it only creates second class once. So if executed twice, the result would be:

```
<div class="class1"><div class="class2"></div></div>
<div class="class1"></div></div>

document.getElementsByClassName('class1')[0].appendChild(secondDiv)
```

Any help?

Comment: Where does the extra `</div>` come from? And where are you using `document.getElementsByClassName('class1')[0].appendChild(secondDiv)`? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Yup, I think that the question could be stated in a bit more descriptive way.

Comment: I can't duplicate this. If [I call the function twice I get](https://jsfiddle.net/vsyLphou/) two sets of div groups with class2 instead of class1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't include appending the dynamic HTML to the document. But when that's done, the output is as expected.

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container");

function createClass() {
 const firstDiv = document.createElement('div')
 firstDiv.classList.add('class1')
 container.appendChild(firstDiv)

 const secondDiv = document.createElement('div')
 secondDiv.classList.add('class2')
 firstDiv.appendChild(secondDiv)
 
 // Your post doesn't include appending the first div to the document
 container.appendChild(firstDiv);
}

createClass();
createClass();
console.log(container.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The OPs code works. Class2 gets appended to class1 on each occasion.

Comment: @Andy I know that. I'm showing that the code does work when appended to the document.